# How long does it take for NPM registry to propagate globally?

Tags: npm, registry, yarnpkg

I've noticed from time to time, after I publish a package, it will not upgraded on yarn or npm, e.g., `npm info` will show the old version. The website will show that the new version exists though. I then disconnect my North America VPN and get European IP, and :tada: the newest version of the package is shown. How long does it take for NPM registry to upgrade globally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about the propagation, but the cache stays for 5 minutes so I guess that's the best answer I can give.

```
Cache-Control: public, max-age=300
```